How to allow (temporary) verbose logging for a child logger in Python
I have a project-wide parent logger
logger = logging.getLogger("project")

and all the loggers I use throughout the project are child loggers of this main logger:
submodule_logger = logging.getLogger("project").getChild(__name__)

If I set the level of the main logger to e.g. "WARNING", then only warning messages from all my submodules get emitted, which works nicely and as intended.
I now want to allow more verbose logging, but only from a specific submodule. For example, for some workflows, it would be nice to know in more detail what my submodule A.B.C is doing, so I would like to set that logger level to "INFO", and also have my main project logger makes an exception and allows "INFO" level messages from my "project.A.B.C" logger to also be emitted, while maintaining a "WARNING" level for all other submodules.
Is there any convenient way to achieve this? Many thanks in advance.

Are you just missing the fact that you can call setLevel on any logger to override the level it inherits from its parent? logging.getLogger("project.A.B.C").setLevel(logging.INFO)

You might want to use logging.config.fileConfig so you can make this change at startup just by editing configuration file, rather than your code itself, or look at logging.config.listen to allow changing the logging system while the program is running.

@chepner I did try this, but if I understand logging correctly (which I may not), this simply means that the submodule logger will keep track of INFO level logs, pass them on to the main logger, who will throw them away since they're below WARNING level.

I think you misunderstand how loggers work (or I am misunderstanding your question).
import logging

logging.basicConfig()

main = logging.getLogger("project")
child = main.getChild("A.B.C")

main.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
child.setLevel(logging.INFO)

child.info("detailed information")  # This gets output
main.info("ignore this")  # This does not

# Both of these get output
child.warning("child warning")
main.warning("main warning")

